# Cannot see images from my computer on my website in HTML

Tags: html, image, filepath

I'm trying to add an image into my HTML file directly from my computer but it wont show up on my webpage.

I have a folder named portfolio containing my HTML file and CSS file. Under portfolio I have another folder named images containing all my images I wish to use.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 <div class="project-grid">
       <img class="project-image" src="images/project-1.jpg" />
      <img class="project-image" src="images/project-2.jpg" />
      <img class="project-image" src="images/project-3.jpg" />
      <img class="project-image" src="images/project-4.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Open the developer tools (usually F12), on network tab, select the GET requests for those images, and update your question with the error responses

Comment: Request URL: file:///C:/Users/Guest/Documents/Portolio/images/project-1.jpg

Comment: For me it was probably the browser itself. If you think it's the website, it maybe the image was not found. Define it by adding the previous file path

Comment: And what is the error response? IS the path identical to your images real location?

Answer (score 0):

this would be correct if the folder "images" is inside the "portfolio" folder

try using src="../images/project-4.jpg" instead

edit:
if by "under" it you mean inside it, try changing the "../" with "./"
it could also be a typing mistake so make sure to copy the folder/images names

Answer (score 0):

images folder and the file (index.html) in which you are using these images
must be in same root directory (portfolio) folder.

```
 ---  index.html(file)
|
|         <div class="project-grid">
|            <img class="project-image" src="images/project-1.jpg" />
|            <img class="project-image" src="images/project-2.jpg" />
|            <img class="project-image" src="images/project-3.jpg" />
|            <img class="project-image" src="images/project-4.jpg" />
|         </div>
|    
|
|
 ---  images(folder)

         project-1.jpg
         project-2.jpg
         project-3.jpg
         project-4.jpg
```